# How to change the hostname of Ubuntu in docker?

Tags: ubuntu, docker

When using Ubuntu in docker , there is no way to modify the hostname; each time to connect to ubuntu, hostname is a random string ....

Answer (score 4):

#### Docker run

If you are running the container using `docker run`, then you can use [`-h`](https://docs.docker.com/edge/engine/reference/commandline/run/) option as said by @callmemath

```
docker run -h custom.hostname -ti ubuntu bash
```

---

#### Docker-compose

If you are running containers using docker-compose then you need to use [hostname](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#domainname-hostname-ipc-mac_address-privileged-read_only-shm_size-stdin_open-tty-user-working_dir).

```
hostname: Any_name_you_like
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `-h` option :

```
docker run -h custom.hostname -ti ubuntu bash
root@custom:/# hostname
custom.hostname
```

See [docker run documentation](https://docs.docker.com/edge/engine/reference/commandline/run/) for more details